# Add left navigation bar on github pages with .md files

Tags: github, jekyll, documentation, github-pages

I want to create some documentation for our project in GitHub.

I can see, that GitHub already provides these options with GitHub pages. In the intro video, I can see that you can and multiple pages (.md files) and navigation.

I already add Jekyll.

But:

- I can't find how to add a left navigation bar
- how to organise files so that it will know where to find other pages

Right now I have

```
-> Root
  |
  -> _config.yml
  -> about.md
  -> index.md
  -> README.md
  -> docs
     |
     -> first_page.md
     -> second_page.md
```

The config file I have

```
title: title
description: YOUR DESCRIPTION
baseurl: 'our_domain'
kramdown:
  math_engine: mathjax
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
plugins:
  - jekyll-default-layout

# Navigation
# List links that should appear in the site sidebar here
navigation:
  - text: Documentation
    internal: true
    url: ./docs
```

Comment: You have to pick a theme that supports a nav bar on the left side; one example: https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *just the docs* theme mentioned by Benjamin includes a sidebar in the default layout using `{% include components/sidebar.html %}` This [sidebar.html](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/blob/main/_includes/components/sidebar.html) is very interesting but a quite complex example on how to do it, including other files, etc.

In short:

1. Adjust your layout.
2. Loop over some kind of data file, or in your case site.navigation
3. Use the returned information (text, internal, url) and include it in your sidebar.

Very simple example:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {% for item in site.navigation %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The [Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/navigation/) include simpler examples on how to loop such files. The docs also explain how to use a YAML file in the _data folder for this instead.